# Extract Values To Points using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro gives arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010555: Internal error in Sample

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, error-010555

I have built an ArcPy tool that works using Python 2.7. I am trying to use the same tool but now using Python 3. When trying to perform ExtractValuesToPoints of ArcPy I keep getting the following error:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010555: Internal error in Sample:
>   %s. ERROR 002834: The geometry operation was cancelled. Workspace or
>   data source is read only. Workspace or data source is read only. The
>   table was not found. [VAT_mixed_ht_raster_with_blocks] The table was
>   not found. [VAT_mixed_ht_raster_with_blocks] ERROR 002834: The
>   geometry operation was cancelled. Failed to execute
>   (ExtractValuesToPoints).

Executing with Python 2.7, the tool runs fine.

code:

```
arcpy.gp.ExtractValuesToPoints(pt_file, ht_raster, observers)
```

Does it have anything to do with **gp**?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [`arcpy.sa.ExtractValuesToPoints()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-values-to-points.htm) function which:

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.