# ArcGIS Pro Classify Raster Failure ERROR 002834

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, land-classification, image-segmentation, image-classification

I am trying to run the `Classify Raster` tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 using an .ecd file generated from the ISO Classifier tool. I am using a composite of Sentinel bands run through the PCA tool and an additional SRTM layer to do the classification for the study area. The PCA layers, Composite image, and ISO Classifier ECD file generated just fine, but when I try to run the Classify Raster tool, I keep getting the 002834 error. I have tried to change the parameters, use different imagery as inputs into the tool, use alternative ECD files, but nothing seems to work. When I try to look up the error on the ArcGIS Pro website, there seems to be no documentation related to it.

How can I work around this error?

Comment: When I searched on "002834 error arcgis pro" I found the GIS SE Question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/extract-values-to-points-using-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro-gives-arcgisscripting-execu  , the error text of which indicates a permission or format issue. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of Pro in use (it will start with "2.")

Comment: Hi Vince, I mistakenly used my ArcGIS Desktop version. My Pro version in 2.5